# Cat unix command multithread safe ? Looking for parallel mysql restore on several hosts

Tags: mysql, bash, subprocess, python-asyncio

I am trying to pipe output of cat file into external host. Planning to do this asynchronously to multiple hosts the same file. Can someone shed insights into potential problems with the technicalities

#### Details

File being transferred: mysql dump of 3GB

Time taken to transfer onto one host - 9 min

Python program

```
async def run_command_shell(command):
    """Run command in subprocess (shell).""
    # Create subprocess
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    # Status
    print("Started:", command, "(pid = " + str(process.pid) + ")", flush=True)

    # Wait for the subprocess to finish
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()

def main():
    commands = ["cat mysqldump | mysql -u -p -h <hostA>", "cat mysqldump | mysql -u -p -h <hostB>"]
    tasks = [
        run_command_shell(c)
        for c in commands
    ]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    commands = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    results = loop.run_until_complete(commands)
    print(results)
```

#### Goal

I have to restore replication across 20 hosts as soon as possible. Ideally I need to restore the mysqldump on 20 hosts at the same time so that I can restore replication in ~10 min. If there are any potential limitations I need to aggressively batch them into minimum possible batches to have minimal time of broken replication on any host.

#### Questions

1. Is Cat unix command thread safe? can multiple sub process (in each subshell) read from the same file without any issue? Are there any alternatives?
2. Any potential upper limit on the performance of the machine I should be looking? So that I can batch the number of commands I have to run at a time.
3. How does python asyncio work would that split into multiple threads? which is it's own thread?

Answer (score 0):

**Safe: yes**

*Reading* essentially cannot be unsafe.  *Writing* is where threads can step on each other.

As I understand it, you have 20 threads reading one file 'simultaneously' and writing stuff to the network, and everything else is on 20 other machines.

The 20 threads won't step on each other in reading the one dump file; in fact they may be helping each other because the blocks of the file will be cached for 19 threads.

However, 20 client `mysqls`, all pounding on the network is likely to cause contention there.  Sure, they are mostly "pushing" stuff outward, but there is some minor actions coming back.  Again, all is "safe".

**An improvement**

What would be better is 20 threads of this:

```
cat dump | ssh -h hostN ... "mysql -h localhost ..."
```

That is, run the 20 mysql clients remotely.  Now the only traffic is 20 copies of the file going across the network.  It will probably saturate the network, thereby limiting the overall speed.

**Maybe even faster**

Compress (gzip or whatever) the dump file to a new file (once).  Then 20 of these:

```
cat dump.gz | ssh -h histN ... "(gunzip | mysql -h localhost ...)"
```

This may cut the network traffic down by a factor of about 3.  But it is slowed by the unzipping and by the original zip.  I don't know whether it will really get the job completed sooner.

(No, 20 gzip's would not be good -- it would swamp your CPU cores.)

(Sorry, I don't know the details of ssh, etc.)